# How do I find the vector potential in this question (4)?

Tags: electromagnetic

[image: The 4th question]

How do I find the vector potential in this question? What exactly is the 'region' being referred to?

I am using [equation 334 in this](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node38.html). I am not able to get the bounds to integrate the formula with. Is z infinite? What would the radius vector be?

Comment: Which text book are your referring? If so, it would have covered equations for [vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential). Region seems to be a cylindrical region defined by the inner radius `a` and outer radius `b`. Try to make your question more specific. Tell us exactly where you are stuck. [edit] your question to include more details of what you already know and what you have tried.

Comment: The question is from a problem set. Yes, the equation is covered in the text, but while using the equation where should I integrate? What would the bounds of z be and how would I formulate the vector R which appears in the denominator of the equation?

Comment: Please add the equation you are using into the question.

Comment: If I an not mistaken, `z` will vary from \$-\infty\$ to \$\infty\$ since they don't specify if the current density `J` is bounded along the `z` axis. It looks like a *hollow, thick cylinder* of current flowing along the \$\hat{k}\$ direction.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a hollow thick infinitely long cylinder. But then, I am not able to find the 'region' over which to integrate

Comment: The region is where the current density is non-zero. I would say \$0 < \phi < 2*pi\$, \$-\infty < z < \infty\$, \$a < \rho < b\$. (assuming they mean the cylindrical co-ordinate \$\rho\$ is represented by \$r\$).

Comment: But if z is infinite would be final expression be finite? Also, what would the radius vector be?

Comment: What they have shown is a general formula. If you plan to follow cylindrical co-ordinates, you it will be a triple integral of the form \$\int_\rho \int_\phi \int_z (\cdot) d\rho d\phi dz\$. Don't forget to correctly include the [volume form for cylindrical co-ordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Line_and_volume_elements).

Comment: Yes, I have used the cylindrical form. But I am still not able to understand how the radius vector in the denominator should be written

Comment: Since the distance to the infinitesimal volume element appears in the denominator (as \$|r - r'|\$, I think the integral will be finite as current at infinite distance contributes only \$1/\infty\$ to the integral).

Comment: In cylindrical co-ordiantes, it looks like a pain. [Link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3612484), [Link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2410899), [Link 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1506706), [Link 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2906631). See if the problem becomes easier in any other co-ordinate system. Or if you can exploit the symmetry in the current distribution.

Comment: Would it be right to say that the radius vectors could be assumed to be in the k unit vector direction ? As we're confining our calculations in the hollow cylinder

Comment: I don't think so. If you mean \$\rho\$, it is always \$\perp\$ to \$\hat{k}\$. If you mean the vector \$(r-r')\$ joining the current location to the current density element, then also, no.

Comment: Yeah I meant the latter, because of the hollow cylinder setup

Comment: Since the problem is symmetric in the variables \$\phi\$ and \$z\$, I think this problem can be solved without having to do the triple integration. Not sure how, though.